# Reduce running time of PowerShell script

Tags: performance, powershell, export-to-csv, member, active-directory-group

I'm running a script that first gets all Groups and then gets all members of those collected groups and put those in a .csv.

I'm now waiting for more than 3 hours already and it's not even half way there...

Below is the script.

```
Get-QADGroup -SizeLimit 0 -properties * | 
Select samaccountname| 
Export-CSV D:\Test_PowerShell\group.csv -NoTypeInformation

Get-Content "D:\Test_PowerShell\group.csv" | 
foreach-object {$group = $_ -replace '"', ""# grab current group name get-qadgroupmember $group -sizelimit 0 -indirect | 
`select-object samaccountname,@{n="GroupName";e={$group}}} | 
export-csv D:\Test_PowerShell\groupandmem.csv -notypeinformation
```

Comment: Do you have a lot of nested groups, with groups being members of multiple groups?

Comment: The problem that I see is that the get-qadgroupmember is slow in picking up all the users in the group. 

is there a way to simultaneously extract the users out more than 1 group at a time?

Comment: Yes there are a number of nested groups but don't know how many and how many levels deep.

Comment: If you've got a lot of duplication in your group nesting, you may be able to speed it up by caching results to eliminate repetitive lookups.

Comment: It's possible to multi-thread the lookups, but the overhead of creating multiple processes could easily be counter-productive.

Comment: I have found something about Multi-thread scripting. but having a hard time to understand it. I will still dig in to it. but maybe some of you can quickly see through it if it could work.

http://www.get-blog.com/?p=22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
( Get-QADGroup -SizeLimit 0 ) | 
foreach-object {                    
                 $group = $_.samaccountname
                 get-qadgroupmember $_.samaccountname -sizelimit 0 -indirect | 
                 select-object samaccountname, @{n="GroupName";e={$group}}
               }
```

**If you are in powershell version 3.0/4.0** you can try using a powershell workflow (I have not done any extensive testing about the performance but theoretically can at least double the speed):

```
workflow get-UserAndGroup 
{
   $a = inlinescript {   add-pssnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement
                        Get-QADGroup -SizeLimit 0 | select -expa samaccountname
                    }                           

   foreach -parallel ( $group in $a ) 
   {                    
     inlinescript {
                    add-pssnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement
                    Get-qadgroupmember $using:group -sizelimit 0 -indirect | 
                    select-object samaccountname, @{n="GroupName";e={$using:group}}
                  } 
    } 
}
```

use like this:

```
 get-UserAndGroup | select samaccountname, groupname | export-csv .\myfile.csv -notypeinformation
```

**My performance test ( with 30 groups containing from 5 to 50 users ):**

```
PS C:\ps> workflow get-UserAndGroup 
{
   $a = inlinescript {   add-pssnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement
                        Get-QADGroup  -SizeLimit 0 | select -expa samaccountname
                    }



   foreach -parallel ( $group in $a ) 
   {                    
     inlinescript {
                    add-pssnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement
                    Get-qadgroupmember $using:group -sizelimit 0 -indirect | 
                    select-object samaccountname, @{n="GroupName";e={$using:group}}
                  } 
    } 
}

PS C:\ps> Measure-Command { get-UserAndGroup }


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 23
Milliseconds      : 512
Ticks             : 235120228
TotalDays         : 0,000272129893518519
TotalHours        : 0,00653111744444444
TotalMinutes      : 0,391867046666667
TotalSeconds      : 23,5120228
TotalMilliseconds : 23512,0228


PS C:\ps> measure-command {
( Get-QADGroup -SizeLimit 0 ) | 
foreach-object {                    
                 $group = $_.samaccountname
                 get-qadgroupmember $_.samaccountname -sizelimit 0 -indirect | 
                 select-object samaccountname, @{n="GroupName";e={$group}}
               }}


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 1
Seconds           : 7
Milliseconds      : 16
Ticks             : 670161451
TotalDays         : 0,000775649827546296
TotalHours        : 0,0186155958611111
TotalMinutes      : 1,11693575166667
TotalSeconds      : 67,0161451
TotalMilliseconds : 67016,1451
```

Comment: the script is working nice, but with the same pulling speed of users. There are a lot of groups with many, many users in it. 

is there a way tot simultaneaously extract users out more groups at a time?

Comment: @Rudy86 Try with workflow if you are in versione 3.0 or above.

Comment: How do I save the Workflow? as what extension? .ps1 also?

Comment: @Rudy86 Yes. USe them as you use functions. I've added one performance test I've done

Comment: I'm getting this error code, don't know where to put the missing opening '('.

[PS] D:\Test_PowerShell>.\PS_Group_Member_Paralel.ps1
Missing opening '(' after keyword 'foreach'.
At D:\Test_PowerShell\PS_Group_Member_Paralel.ps1:7 char:12
+    foreach  <<<< -parallel ( $group in $a )
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (OpenParenToken:TokenId) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingOpenParenthesisAfterKeyword

Comment: Yes that was the prob. the script is now running for the first time. 100 groups in 20 min. 

still testing now with the old script with 100 groups. i'll keep you posted

Comment: My original script needs 9 HOURS to get all groups+members. Just some info about the performance of the script.

Comment: @Rudy86 And now, howm any time it need? If you find this a good answer remeber to check it and give an upvote!

Comment: I get a timeout error when I want to run the script with the sizelimit set to 0

The operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:00:30. The time allotted to this operation may have
been a portion of a longer timeout.
At get-UserAndGroup:9 char:9
+
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [], TimeoutException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : JobStateFailed

Comment: How may groups and user you have?

Comment: round about 17000 users

Comment: @Rudy86 You need to split in more chunks ( IMOA about 20 chunks it will be fine ) the groups array. There is a long story about the limit in `foreach -parallel` and your is the case. I'm sorry but the only solution is split the groups lists in chunks of about 500/600 items for chunk or less.

Comment: thanks, have a test result now of all my O groups. 20 min in the old script and 8 min. in the parallel script. I will go for it.

Going to spilt all groups in chuck of all a, b, c, d... groups and then run the get users.

Comment: @Rudy86 Finally we found a solutions! Glad to help!

Comment: @ruby86 In powershell 4.0 the `foreach -parallel` has a new parameter `-ThrottleLimit`, maybe is useful in this case. If you can upgrade to 4.0 try it and please let us know if the timeout issue is solved. Thank you!